# Use of preposition and prepositional adverb

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, adverbs

I know that prepositions are not supposed to end a sentence; however, I have also read that some prepositions function as adverbs, as seen in "come inside" and "run around."

My question concerns an ambiguous case of both of these types of prepositions in one sentence:

> "**The two ideas differ in the language *with* which they are referred *to*.**"

I have tried writing the previous sentence in a variety of ways:

- "...in the language with which they are referred." (The preposition *with* doesn't agree with *referred*.)
- "...in the language to which they are referred." (This implies a different meaning of *refer*.)
- "...in the language they are referred to with." (This ends the sentence with the preposition *with*.)

But it seems like the sentence above, in bold, is written the best. So my questions are:

- Is this, indeed, the correct way to write this sentence?
- Is there an effective way to eliminate either or both *with* and *to*, while preserving the sentence's meaning?
- Are there many other examples where this structure would be the case, or is this a rare occurrence?

Comment: In principle, the language with which *this* sentence is referred to is English. But English it ain't.

Comment: *I know that prepositions are not supposed to end a sentence ...* This is a case where a supposed rule continues to survive, without anyone actually agreeing with it.  The same applies to never splitting an infinitive ('to boldly go ..."), and neither of these rules apply to common / accepted usage at all.  So you can say: "Do you know yet which high school your daughter is going to go to?", and it is perfectly fine.  If you said: "Do you know yet the high school to which your daughter is going to go?" - you might be technically correct, but that is all, so you would avoid it.

Comment: I agree *With what language did he refer to his idea?* almost seems a credible question. But in practice ***in** what language..?* would be more likely in the incredibly unlikely context where you might ask such a question in anything like that form. And in OP's context, an alternative to *referred to* (such as *described* or *articulated*) would probably make more sense at the semantic level.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a *complex sentence* that contains an independent clause and a dependent clause with a relative pronoun as in your example, it is better to separate it to two sentences (clauses).

> The two ideas differ in the language
>
> They (the two ideas) are referred to with the language.

Both sentences have the same word *language* which will be an antecedent for a relative clause that follows an independent clause:

> The two ideas differ in the ***language*** which they are referred to ***with***.

The preposition *with* could be placed before which.

> The two ideas differ in the language  ***with*** which they are
>   referred to.

There is no way to omit the preposition ***to*** as it is part of the phrasal verb ***refer to***. If you are concerned with the preposition, you could consider changing *refer to* to ***mention***, ***describe***, or ***specify*** , etc. as follows:

> The two ideas differ in the language  ***with*** which they are
>   mentioned/described/specified.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the most natural option is to say:

> The two ideas differ in the language which they are referred to in

But better still would be to rephrase it even more:

> In X [the language you're talking about] the two ideas differ